# Display values from table from a database into a dropdown list

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
   include 'ASEngine/AS.php';

   if(!$login->isLoggedIn())
       header("Location: login.php");
   $user = new ASUser(ASSession::get("user_id"));
   $userInfo = $user->getInfo();

   //basic include files
   require_once("../db.php");

   $nav = 'hotels';

   $hotel_id = '1';

   //Messages
   include 'inc/messages.php';

   $sql1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT room_type_name FROM hotel_room_type WHERE hotel_id = '$hotel_id'");

?>
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="form-row row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <label class="form-label span3">Room Name</label>
            <?php echo "<select>";
                echo "<option value=''>Select One</option>"; 
                $results =  $conn->query($sqll);
                foreach ($results as $data) {
                   echo "<option>$data[room_type_name]</option>";  
                }
               echo "</select>";
           ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting values from a table from a database and the values should be displayed inside a dropdown list. I have used the above code but it is not displaying anything. Can anyone help in this issue?

Comment: What is it displaying? This should at least display something because you are using `echo`.

Comment: First, you assign the query to `$sql1` and never use it. I don't know the framework you are using, but you call `$conn->query` after that. The variable you pass in to that is `$sqll`, the first is a number at the end, the second is a lower case L. Aside from that, try `echo "<option>{$data[room_type_name]}</option>";`

Comment: its displaying "Select one" only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo

```
 $results =  $conn->query($sqll);
```

should be

```
 $results =  $conn->query($sql1);
```

it is a one, not an L

Comment: You will have to supply more information. It still not working isn't much to work with. Did you test (with a print_r() command for example) whether `$results` holds any values?